# HDInsight: Selection method not accepting Storage account

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

While deploying an HDInsight cluster, under `Data Source`, regardless of what Selection Method I choose ('From all subscriptions' or 'Access key'), I am unable attach my storage account. I have created a new storage account in SE Asia region (it was created separately from 'Storage') and wish to use it.

Here's what I do:

PART ONE: Selection method: `From all subscriptions` - 
[image]

1. Configure required settings (Follow 1, 2 and 3 in the screenshot)

[image]

All good till here.

2. It says "Fetching access key". So far, so good. It also chooses the default container.

[image]

3. Then it throws this error:

[image]

PART TWO: Selection method: `Access key` -

1. I select 'Access Key', put in the Storage name, it picks up the Default container.. which is all good.

[image]

2. Then I paste the Access Key from the Storage account

[image]

3. Then it throws this error:

[image]

The storage account is `Standard/Hot` (LRS) and the HDInsight cluster type is `Windows`. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: To add to my post, I've used both the Access keys, and also refreshed one of it to see if that works, but hasn't.

Comment: Just to clarify: Your storage account *is* Premium? Or it's *not*?

Comment: Not Premium. It IS Standard. Sorry about that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Premium storage accounts as well and Standard Hot/Cold storage accounts are not supported with HDInsight. Only supported storage option is [General-purpose Storage Account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-create-storage-account/)

Thanks,
Ashish Thapliyal
Microsoft Corp.

Comment: It isn't Premium. It is standard. Sorry about the typo!

Comment: And its not hot/cold storage either, storage account and hdinsight cluster are in same datacenter,

Comment: If you see the 'Access Key' section, the DCs are the same. Besides, I did change the DC on 'From all subscription' AFTER I got the error, but it threw the same error after that.

Comment: Can you check the properties of storage account and see what is the value for Performance/Access tier?

Comment: Copy/Pasted: `Standard/Hot`

Comment: Status is Available

Comment: Standard/Hot is not supported in HDInsight. Please create or select General-purpose Storage Account https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-create-storage-account/

Comment: 'Account Kind' is General Purpose and Blog Storage, and each of them have 'Standard' Performance option. Does HDInsight not need Blob type storages? Also, I created a Genera Purpose kind account and noticed it has a Blob under it. How is that different from Blog Storage Account kind?

Comment: Yes , HDInsight use blobs. Supporting new storage hot/cold tier is on our backlog

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121280/discussion-between-anonymous-person-and-ashish-thapliyal).

Comment: @AshishThapliyal When will 'support for hot/cold' be available?